# How to write the text data in to the sqlite3 database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have create one sqlite3 database and in that database i am writing name text but when i write in to database it doesn't write only blank row create i am doing like this

```
if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
{
  NSLog(@"ALERT>TEXT===%@",alert.alertText);
  NSLog(@"....");
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [alert.alertText UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_step(statement);

  NSLog(@"insertion is done");
}
```

Comment: FYI: Is it a requirement to use sqlite3 directly? I mean use of CoreData will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to insert data in to my database.

```
 NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into TableName alertName values '%@'",[name stringWithPercentEscape]];
                    NSLog(@"%@",sqlStatement);    

                    if (sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL, NULL, &error)  == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"record inserted successfully!!");
                        NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO YourTable ('symbol') VALUES",%@];

    const char *insertStmt=[insertSQL UTF8String];

    char *errmsg=nil;

    if(sqlite3_exec(db, insertStmt, NULL, NULL, &errmsg)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
         NSLog(@"Row ADDED!");
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Connect to DB]

[image: Get DB path]

[image: Insert into DB function]

Please vote and marked it as answered if it fulfills your requirement.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the FMDB framework.It is a very light package.
With it you can manage your sqlite database just by SQL.

This is the [link](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)